# C Segmentation Fault, multiple warnings

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcat

This is my first post on stackoverflow and I hope I am not breaking any rules or reposting. I have looked for the answers to my warnings. While I can find some kind of similar instances, I cannot get a working fix. Im hoping to get some help.

I need to find a hash collision with hashfunction(myname). So I did some research and put together this recursive function that will test every possible string to the specified length and print the string when it is found. Have a look.

```
void findCollision(char prefix[], int max_length);

int main() {
    printf("Finding collison\n");
    char blank[0] = {'a'};
    findCollision(blank,999);
    printf("Press Enter to Continue");
    while( getchar() != '\n' );
    return 0;
}

void findCollision(char prefix[], int max_length){
    char c;
    char temp[sizeof(prefix)+1];
    for(c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++){
        strcpy(temp, prefix);
        strcat(temp, c);
        if(hashFunction(temp) == -408228925 && temp != 'myname'){
            printf("found it! --->");
            printf("%s", temp);
        }
    }
    for(c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++){
        strcpy(temp, prefix);
        strcat(temp, c);
        if(sizeof(prefix) < max_length){
            findCollision(temp, max_length);
        }
    }
}
```

When compiled with the hash code (I can provide that as well if needed) I get these errors.

```
----------Build Started--------
----------Building project:[ hash - Debug ]----------
/home/mustbelucky/hash/hash.c
22:2: warning: excess elements in array initializer [enabled by default]
22:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘blank’) [enabled by default]
34:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcat’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/string.h
136:14: note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘char’
/home/mustbelucky/hash/hash.c
35:50: warning: character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]
35:47: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]    
42:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcat’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]   
/usr/include/string.h
136:14: note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘char’

----------Build Ended----------
```

I have Googled them but with no success on finding a successful fix. Any thoughts? This project is due in 2 days and I have a feeling its going to have to run for a while.

Comment: Is the code C or C++? Looks like C, so you should drop the c++ tag. Also, these look like they are all compilation warnings. Where is the segmentation fault?

Comment: First of all, fix the warnings! They are there for a reason. Secondly you should run your program in a debugger. It will help you locate where the crash is, as well as let you examine variables to help you figure out the reason behind the crash.

Comment: First of all, learn C... For example, 'myname' is not string in C, you want "myname" instead. There's just too many details you need to learn, that you can't learn them by asking other people "why isn't my code C", which is essentially what you are doing here, so grab a tutorial first!

Comment: I have to agree with Joachim. you should never expect any C code that has warnings to run the way you expect unless you full understand the meaning of the warning and have confirmed that the behavior on your Archetecture/Compiler is what you expect (almost never the case). Fixing the warnings will also teach you a lot about the language.

Comment: @crashmstr , sorry about the C++ tag. I'm trying to learn C (we don't deal with this "pickyness" in java) and

Comment: sorry new to the site .. tried a new line and it sent the comment and wouldn't let me edit past five mins.................. @crashmstr , sorry about the C++ tag. --- tletnes and Joachim Pileborg , i'm trying to fix the warnings.(the reason for this post) and hyde how do i say this without being banned .. I'm trying to learn C and i don't have time to read through an entire intro to c book (school work internship), I googled them and couldn't find the answers so I came here to learn. I recommend not discouraging learning by condescendingly suggesting it. Thought about that thanks. :)

Comment: @user1866949 The best way to get help here when you ask is to show that you have tried to help yourself. We have all bee in the place of having what seems like a stupid question, so we understand how frustrating it is. what you want to do is reduce your error or warning to the absolute minimum number of lines to replicate it (I usually try to build programe consisting of a "main" of less than 5-10 lines) by pruning my code untill I get that error and (if possible) no others, if that does highlight the issue to you, then it is time to ask here.

Answer (score 2):

`char blank[0] = {'a'};`

declares a zero length array of chars but you fill it with an aray of length 1

`strcat(temp, c);`

trys to cat temp, which is a char[] to c which is a char. both arguments should be char* or char[]

I think there are other errors reported beyond the code segment you provide.

Edit:

`temp != 'myname'`

seems to be trying to test if `temp` matches `'myname'`, but `'myname'` is a character litereal (if this even compiles it would proably be 'm', and temp is a char[], you want to use `strcmp(temp, "myname") != 0`

Comment: And C does not allow zero length arrays, regardless of what GCC does.

Comment: And I think `char temp[sizeof(prefix)+1];` will give you an array length equal to the size of a pointer + 1.  The `sizeof()` operation is a compile time calculation and can't determine at runtime the length of the array passed into your findCollision() function.

Answer (score 0):

The warnings are actually pretty self-explanatory here.

```
22:2: warning: excess elements in array initializer [enabled by default]
```

This means you're putting more elements in the array than you made space for.

```
34:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcat’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

This means that the 2nd argument should be a pointer, but you're giving it a char/int.

The other warnings seem to be from other code.

At least one reason for your segfault is because `sizeof` will not do what you want here.